# how to cancel arbitrary term in fractional formula

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I often encounter this kind of problem that I want the fractional formula to be looked like the way I want it to be. For example, this one

$$\frac{R^2 \left(g m_1-g m_2\right)}{J+m_1 R^2+m_2 R^2}$$

I want it to be like this

$$\frac{g \left(m_1-m_2\right)}{\frac{J}{R^2}+m_1+m_2}$$

to change $g m_1-g m_2$ into $g \left(m_1-m_2\right)$ is easy by using `Factor` in algebraic palette.

but I have not figured out an easy way to cancel $R^2$ in both enumerator and denominator, unless I deleted $R^2$ manually.

A more general question is how to cancel arbitrary term in fractional formula?

Answer (score 3):

You might find it helpful to define [`TransformationFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformationFunctions.html), which is an option to FullSimplify.

For example:

```
t[term_][expr_] := 
 Simplify[Numerator[expr]/term]/Simplify[Denominator[expr]/term]

expr = R^2 (g m[1] - g m[2])/(J + m[1] R^2 + m[2] R^2);

FullSimplify[expr, 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t[R^2]}]
(* (g (m[1] - m[2]))/(J/R^2 + m[1] + m[2]) *)
```

While not automatic (and you should be careful that `term` cannot be 0), it does add something to a toolbox.

Comment: It seems it only works with `t[R^2]`. I tried `t[p^2]`, then nothing happens.

Comment: @matheorem I don't know what you mean, but `FullSimplify` will reject a transformation if the result is more complex, as defined by the [`ComplexityFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html).

Comment: @matheorem can you provide what you actually did?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Well, the reason that I want to divide numerator and denominator by $R^2$ is that I want the $J/R^2$, because $J/R^2$ has a special meaning. If $J/p^2$ has a special meaning, then I have to divide $p^2$.

Comment: @matheorem What I meant is that `t[p^2]` works for me on the example in the Q.  I assumed you tried it on another expression and it didn't work.  You might try applying `t[p^2]` directly to the expression.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That is odd! I tried, it didn't work. I am using M10

Comment: @matheorem Both `FullSimplify[e2, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, t[p^2]}]` and `t[p^2][e2]` give `(g (m[1] - m[2]))/(J/p^2 + m[1] + m[2])` where `e2 = (p^2 (g m[1] - g m[2]))/(J + p^2 m[1] + p^2 m[2])`.  It's not the same with you?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh, I mean divide `R^2 (g m[1] - g m[2])/(J + m[1] R^2 + m[2] R^2)` by `p^2`, not `(p^2 (g m[1] - g m[2]))/(J + p^2 m[1] + p^2 m[2])`

Comment: @matheorem Ah, that simplification (cancellation of  `p^2`) is automatic.  It would need to be held in some way.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to make this. For example, this one is simple, but is a bit not regular, that is, depends upon the structure of the expression at hand:

```
  expr = (R^2*(g*m1 - g*m2))/(J + m1*R^2 + m2*R^2);

(expr /. J -> j*R^2 // Simplify) /. j -> J/R^2

(* (g (m1 - m2))/(m1 + m2 + J/R^2)   *)
```

This one is more regular though a bit longer:

```
(Factor[Numerator[expr]]/R^2)/Map[Divide[#, R^2] &, Denominator[expr]]

(*   (g (m1 - m2))/(m1 + m2 + J/R^2)   *)
```

Generally, there is a package "Presentation Master" of David Park, that has a subpackage "Manipulations". The latter contains a dozen of functions designed precisely  for such purposes. With the help of that one can transform any expression to any desired form. I strongly recommend using it.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, another version of Chuy's answer, only simpler:

```
expr = R^2 (g m[1] - g m[2])/(J + m[1] R^2 + m[2] R^2);
Simplify[Numerator[expr]/R^2]/Simplify[Denominator[expr]/R^2]
```

This could be put into a function, but the point is that the use of `TransformationFunction` inside `Simplify` is unnecessary, I think.

I'm new to this game and I'm struggling with exactly these issues myself.

Hope this helps

Comment: Please post the output of your solution too, so that it can be compared with that of other answers.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps,

```
With[{n = Simplify[Numerator[expr]/R^2], 
  d = Simplify[Denominator[expr]/R^2]}, n/d]
```

this yields:(g (m1 - m2))/(m1 + m2 + J/R^2)